# DeviantArt Oauth authentication with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0

I am trying to get an Oauth access token through JavaScript. In partilar I want to authenticate to [DeviantArt API](https://www.deviantart.com/developers/authentication) keeping as simple as it can be. Here are my approaches, I only need one but anyone is working so just one solution for any of the will be enough.

1. Since it is a Cross-Origin I tried using ajax. This is the code:

   ```
   var response_type = "code";
   var client_id =  "1234"; //Random clientId for stackoverflow
   var redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8080/my-project/authDeviantArt.html";
   var authorization1 = "https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/authorize";
   var authorization2 = "https://www.deviantart.com/oauth2/token";
   var client_secret = "qwerty12345"; //Random secret for stackoverflow
   var grant_type1 = "authorization_code";
   var grant_type2 = "client_credentials";
   var scopes = "basic";

   //Using The Authorization Code Grant
   var request1 = authorization1+'?response_type='+response_type+'client_id='+client_id+'&redirect_uri='+redirect_uri;
   //Using The Client Credentials Grant
   var request2 = authorization2+'?client_id='+client_id+'&client_secret='+client_secret+'&grant_type='+grant_type2;

   $.ajax({
      url: request1,
      dataType: "jsonp",
      success: function (res){
      console.log("Response: "+res.access_token);
   });
   ```

The problem is that I allways get the following error

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :

but clicking on the error in the JavasCript console I can see the response JSON:

```
{"access_token":"662b..5d58","token_type":"Bearer","expires_in":3600,"status":"success"}
```

and the Concole.log prints `Error: [object Object]` (despite chrome console does not throw any error in that line).

2. I also tried with the library [JSO](https://github.com/andreassolberg/jso) but I don't achieve saving the token neither.
3. I also tried with the library Hello.js but it does not support DeviantArt and my approaches modifying it had neither any success.
4. I tried also trying to modify headers in XMLHttpRequest() or adding options to getJson but always CORS error, no matter what I try.

I have been trying tens of solutions posted on stackoverflow but no one works for me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem while trying to obtain a simple client access token, and I've come to the conclusion that the **Deviantart API does not support CORS at all**. I'm not 100% certain, but no attempt of mine (either through ajax or XMLHttpRequest or even [test-cors.org](http://www.test-cors.org)) gave any indication that the response contained the proper CORS header (Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

It would make sense, too. This way of using the API forces you to expose your client secret in your JS code (as you have in your example). I believe the API was meant to be used on the back-end or by programs (either desktop or mobile) that would hide their client secret in their code or some encrypted configuration file. [This comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29175006/ajax-function-w-mailgun-getting-error-request-header-field-authorization-is-n#comment-46758163) on another question led me to that conclusion.

I would recommend you handle the API communication server-side if possible. You may also want to take a look at [their oEmbed implementation](https://www.deviantart.com/developers/oembed).

Comment: Thanks for your response Alan, that would really make sense. I have no access to that code anymore so I can't try a server side implementation, but next time I will take it in mind.